# twitter bootstrap: 2 column container with variable height on one side, and 100% on the other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a container, set to `overflow-x: hidden;`, which contains a series of rows.  The rows are split into two columns.  The left column needs to be able to grow and shrink, as the contents of the right column change.  The layout looks like this:

```
<div class="no-x-overflow">
  <div class="data-row container-fluid">
    <div class="left-column pull-left">
      <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column pull-left">
      <div class="detail-row1"></div>
      <div class="detail-row2"></div>
      <div class="detail-row3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The various `detail-row` divs can be hidden and revealed in the UI, causing the `data-row` to shrink and expand.  The `left-column` div needs to be able to do the same.  What value can I give the `height` on the various parts, to make them work.

Styles:

```
.no-x-overflow {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.data-row {
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

.left-column {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
}

.right-column {
  width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is tough to answer without the context for why the left column needs to grow and shrink to match the right column. For instance, If I was trying to give the left column a background-color or border that matched the same height as the right column I would just give that background color to the container and then apply a different background on the right column. Here's a fiddle for what I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/BY2Xh/1/

```
.data-row {
overflow: auto;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
background: yellow;
}

.left-column {
width: 10%;
box-shadow: 1px 0 0 solid #999;
float: left;
}  

.right-column {
width: 90%;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
float: left;
background: green;
}
```

If you're issue is that you have floating elements following this content and don't want them to fill the empty space created by the shorter left column than you can apply a width and oveflow: auto to the container too.

Also, You're layout won't work as you expect if your width %s add up to 100 and you also have borders or padding. You need to remove the padding from those inner divs, and can apply borders that don't take up space in the DOM with box-shadows.